# Enterprise Architect: MDA transformation to XSD breaks enumeration attributes

Tags: transformation, enterprise-architect

I try to customize the transformation to the XSD PSM. One of the customizations contains the usage of XSDAttributes for source attributes. This works quite fine but I have a single insistent problem regarding enumerations.
My PIM contains some UML enumerations and XSDSimpleTypes which are transformed correctly to the PSM. But when my PIM contains a class attribute with such an enum as attribute type the transformation seems to work fine but it looks like the attribute type in the PSM is not connected to the generated enum. This causes the subsequent generation of XSD schema to throw the warning "Warning no XSD type found for: 'Color'. Default is: xs:string". If I manually select the enumeration "Color" manually in the PSM the schema generation passes without any warnings. With the simpleTypes I have no problems and works well.

The probably relevant part of the attribute transformation is

```
Attribute {
  [...]
  name=%qt%$attName%qt%
  scope="Public"
  type=%qt%%attType%%qt%
  stereotype="XSDattribute"
```

The probably relevant part of the class transformation is

```
%if elemType == "Class"%
  Class
%else%
  Enumeration
%endIf%
  {
    name=%qt%%className%%qt%
```

The relevant part of the intermediary file is:

```
Class
{
  name="Apple"
  stereotype="XSDcomplexType"
  [...]
Attribute
{
  [...]
  name="color"
  scope="Public"
  type="Color"
  stereotype="XSDattribute"
  [...]
}
}

Enumeration
{
  [...]
  name="Color"
  stereotype="enumeration"
  [...]
}
```

Can you tell me where I messed up my transformation?

Regards,
  Stefan

Comment: Have you ever thought about creating XSD from a script? I did that more than once and felt much more comfortable with that than using this awkward proprietary scripting stuff from Sparx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I think the basic XSD MDA template is broken since they introduced the enumeration as a metatype an no longer a stereotype on the metatype Class.

Here's what I did to fix it:
Class Template:

```
%if elemType != "Class" and elemType != "Enumeration" and elemType != "DataType"%
%endTemplate%


Class
{
  name=%qt%%className%%qt%
    %if classStereotype=="enumeration" or elemType == "Enumeration"%
      stereotype="enumeration"
    %elseIf elemType == "DataType"%
      stereotype="XSDsimpleType" 
    %else%
      stereotype="XSDcomplexType"
    %endIf%
  notes=%qt%%qt%
  %TRANSFORM_CURRENT("name","stereotype","notes")%
  %TRANSFORM_REFERENCE("XSDClass")%
%list="Attribute" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
}

%list="Connector" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
```

Attribute Template:

```
Attribute
{
  %TRANSFORM_REFERENCE()%
  %TRANSFORM_CURRENT("scope","type","notes")%
  scope="Public"
  type=%qt%%attType%%qt%
  notes=%qt%%qt%
%if attLowerBound!=""%
  Tag
  {
    name="minOccurs"
    value=%qt%%attLowerBound=="*" ? "unbounded" : value%%qt%
  }
%endIf%
%if attUpperBound!=""%
  Tag
  {
    name="maxOccurs"
    value=%qt%%attUpperBound=="*" ? "unbounded" : value%%qt%
  }
%endIf%
}
```